# UIView animateWithDuration: animating UIButton can't be touched event ios 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiviewanimation

I use this code when i move the button but the event is disabled during the transition

**what can i do to tap when is moving?**
here is my code...

```
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(210, 285, 120, 118);
    [button setTitle:@"" forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(botonTap:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"car.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.view addSubview:button];
```

**moving over screen and disabled event to finish :(**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10
                      delay:0.0f
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction |
 UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{

                     button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 4, 120, 118);

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }];
```

**Dont Enter at this method when tap the button, only works at stop :(**

```
-(IBAction)botonTap:(id)sender {
    button.alpha=0;
}
```

Comment: You want selector method called while animating?

Comment: @SanitLee Thanks that solve my problem !